# How can I nest a with_filetree in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to push config files for various apps (based on group_names) & need to loop thru the config .j2 templates from a list variable. If I use a known list of config templates I can use a standard with_nested like this...

```
template:
  src: '{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/{{ item[1] }}/configs/{{ item[0] }}.j2'
  dest: /path/to/{{ item[1] }}/configs/{{ item[0] }}
with_nested:
  - ['file.1', 'file.2', 'file.3', 'file.4']
  - '{{ group_names }}'
```

However, since each app will have its own configs I can't use a common list for a with_nested. Every attempt to somehow use with_filetree nested fails. Is there any way to nest a with_filetree? Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to deal with this is probably to imbricate loops through an include. I take for granted that your app directory only contains `.j2` files. Adapt if this is not the case.

In e.g. `push_templates.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Copy templates for group {{ current_group }}
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: /path/to/{{ current_group }}/configs/{{ (item.src | splitext).0 | basename }}
  with_filetree: "{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/{{ current_group }}"
  # Or using the latest loop syntax
  # loop: "{{ query('filetree', playbook_dir + '/templates/' + current_group) }}"
  when: item.src is defined
```

*Note*: on the `dest` line, I am removing the last found extension of the file and getting its name only without the leading directory path. Check the [ansible doc on filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) for `splitext` and `basename` for more info

Then in your e.g. `main.yml`

```yaml
- name: Copy templates for all groups
  include_tasks: push_templates.yml
  loop: "{{ group_names }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: current_group
```

Note the `loop_var` in the control section to disambiguate the possible `item` overlap in the included file. The var name is of course aligned with the one I used in the above included file. See the [ansible loops documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) for more info.

---

An alternative approach to the above would be to construct your own data structure looping over your groups with `set_fact` and calling the `filetree` lookup on each iteration (see example above with the newer `loop` syntax), then loop over your custom data structure to do the job.

Comment: Thanks muchly. After updating some var lookups in my .j2 templates, this works exactly as I need it to.